# using the calculation number for the next calculation

Tags: python, loopback

experts.

I'm trying to define a function (`collatz`) that:

1. Asks for a number. If it is even it prints `number // 2`, if it odd it prints `3 * number + 1`. (OK)
2. The result, whatever it is, must enter a loop until the result is 1. (NOK)

So, i´m not figure out because the result is not used and is in an infinite loop. Any suggestion?

```py
def collatz():
    number = int(input('Enter the number: '))
    x = number % 2
    while number != 1:
        if x == 0:
            print(f'{number // 2}')
        else:
            print(f'{3 * number + 1}')
        number = number

print(f'{collatz()}')
```

Comment: Just do `number = number // 2` or `number = 3 * number + 1` and then just `print(number)` once.

Comment: You don't need to worry about that, the Collatz conjecture ensures that it will always converge to 1.  You could try to add an exit condition but you won't be able to test that it works.  Alternatively you could give it a maximum run time (let's say 30 second) and check that execution time is not exceeded at every loop.

Comment: You are not updating the value of number, it is remaining same in the loop

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually assign the result back to `number`.

As well:

- The divisibility check needs to be in the loop.
- The outer `print()` is not needed.
- The f-strings are redundant. `print()` converts its arguments to string automatically.

```
def collatz():
    number = int(input('Enter the number: '))
    while number != 1:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            number //= 2  # Short for "number = number // 2"
        else:
            number = 3*number + 1
        print(number)

collatz()
```

Example run:

```
Enter the number: 3
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
```

Comment: It's works. Thank you so much. Just a little qustion...why we dont't need the orther print? What's the logic?

Comment: @AndersonSilva Try adding it back and see what happens